# web2py - Key error when defining reference to table before table definition

Tags: web2py

this exact error happened to me after upgrading web2py.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/58aG2cdzk8s

I'm using Version 2.11.2-stable.

I don't know how to report this properly. Any ideas?

Also, what more information would you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be considered a bug, which you can report on [Github](https://github.com/web2py/pydal/issues).

For now, the workaround is to set [`lazy_tables=True`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Lazy-Tables) or make sure reference fields refer only to tables that have already been defined.